# Google Maps Android get LatLng array of points from GeoJsonFeature

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How do I get a list of points when clicking on a line that is a geojson feature? I need to access the individual points of each line? This does not work: lineStringFeature.getPolylineOptions().getPoints(). Thank you very much.

```
// Set a listener for geometry clicked events.
layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
        GeoJsonFeature lineStringFeature;
        GeoJsonLineStringStyle lineStringStyle = new GeoJsonLineStringStyle();
        lineStringFeature = (GeoJsonFeature) feature;
        lineStringStyle.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        lineStringStyle.setZIndex(10f);
        lineStringStyle.setWidth(6f);
        lineStringFeature.setLineStringStyle(lineStringStyle);

        // this doesn't work how do you get an array of LatLngs
        lineStringFeature.getPolylineOptions().getPoints().get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GeoJsonFeature` object has a [`getGeometry()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonFeature.html#getGeometry--) method that returns the geometry (you can cast it to `GeoJsonLineString` if you are sure of the type), and the `GeoJsonLineString` object has a [`getCoordinates()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonLineString.html#getCoordinates--) method that returns a `List<LatLng>` with the coordinates:

```
if ("LineString".equalsIgnoreCase(lineStringFeature.getGeometry().getType())) {
    List<LatLng> coordinates = ((GeoJsonLineString) lineStringFeature.getGeometry()).getCoordinates();
    // Do something with the coordinates
} else if ("MultiLineString".equalsIgnoreCase(lineStringFeature.getGeometry().getType())) {
    for (GeoJsonLineString linestring : ((GeoJsonMultilineString) lineStringFeature.getGeometry()).getLineStrings()) {
        List<LatLng> coordinates = linestring.getCoordinates();
        // Do something with the coordinates. Take into account that one MultiLinestring is composed of several Linestrings
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am getting the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonMultiLineString cannot be cast to com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonLineString. So is it a multilinestring? How do I work with that? I just need the start and end LatLng of each polyline on click to add a marker. Thank you!

Comment: You can iterate through the `LinesString`s of your `MultiLineString`. Check my edited answer

Comment: it doesn't seem to recognize getType() or "in" within you for loop.

Comment: Fixed, check now

Comment: Works great! Thank you! If you get a chance and can have a look at my other question, I would appreciate it. I am coming from the javascript api and having a bit of trouble adapting to the android api. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036467/google-maps-android-revert-linestringfeature-back-to-its-original-state